# how to list out all the logged on users in a web application using jsp,servlets

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets

I need to list out all the logged on users information(username) and i have to show the list like online friends list in gmail or orkut. I am using JSP and Servlets. can anybody help me  in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a server side session. For example, you can maintain a HashMap. So, when any new user logged in at that time you need to do entry in that Map. And whenever you need all logged in user's information, you can get it easily.